# Overlay color on image with css and center text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make it so when users hover over an item that is no longer in stock it will show them a message overlay on the image saying no longer in stock. This is working currently but I cannot seem the get the text to float in the absolute center of the block. It floats on the top in the center of the image.

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="store_no_stock_sizer">
        <img src="/com/img/products/1.png" alt="Image">
</div>
<div class="store_page_product_title">Test Item</div>
<p>Out of Stock</p>
```

and the CSS I am using to overlay the image

```
.store_no_stock_sizer {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
}
.store_no_stock_sizer:after {
        opacity: 0;
}
.store_no_stock_sizer:hover:after {
        max-width: 100%;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        outline: none;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 99%;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        background: #000;
        color: #FFF;
        opacity: 0.7;
        content: "OUT OF STOCK";
}
```

Now this DOES WORK but it has the text in the top of the image when they hover over it rather then in the center of the image. I would use padding and such but since its a responsive page and image, I don't want a strict padding set to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: flex` for dynamically centering text,

Also using `align-items: center;` and `justify-content: center;`

Like this:

```
.store_no_stock_sizer:hover:after {
        max-width: 100%;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        outline: none;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 99%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        position: absolute;
        background: #000;
        color: #FFF;
        opacity: 0.7;
        content: "OUT OF STOCK";
}
```

Comment: Thank you this was the perfect fix for the issue!

Comment: No problem, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

`<p>` tags are mostly used for articles and stuff if you need to show an error, you might wanna use `<span>` tag so It would be something like:

```
<span id="error">Your error goes here.</span>
```

css:

```
#error{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    // Or you could use an absolute position and manually set the top and left position of the tag
}
```

Comment: I'm using custom coding with the `<p>` tag. I guess you must be confused as to what I meant by the question, but that P tag is NOT what i am asking about. I am using `content:"Out of stock"` on the css to display an out of stock message on hover of the **image** only. The `<p>` you are referring to is actually only used for displaying current price and since its not it stock it says out of stock...